# Odata v4 - hasPendingChanges

Tags: odata, sapui5

I use **Odata V4** and I check if **submitBatch** method has been failed by checking the result of **hasPendingChanges** method.

```
this.getModel().submitBatch(BATCH_ID).then(function () {
                var bHasErrors = this.getModel().hasPendingChanges(BATCH_ID);
                if (bHasErrors) {
                    this._displayError();
                } else {
                   ...
            }.bind(this)).catch(function () {
                ...
            }.bind(this));
        },
```

If the result of **hasPendingChanges** is true, then batch failed(f.e. 'such value already exists in database') and error message appears. But after fixing duplicated value and resubmit the same error occurs.

The same issue described on SAP [tutorials GitHub page](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/627), but it is still in process...

I tried to delete my batches(sGroupId = "TaskDetailBatch") with array of bathes, but this array always updates the previous condition:
[array from model.oRequestor, where stored all batches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ33d.png)
[Response with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdHAK.png)

Comment: Could you paste in the exact wording of the error messages you get?

Comment: The following error returned(Name should be unique in DB):
"Post on '...' failed: will be repeated automatically - Error: Name already exists".
I added the image to main question